# Akka pipe play promise

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/java/untyped-actors.html#Ask_Send-And-Receive-Future

I want to use this pattern.

I make a WS call in my Actor which returns a F.Promise. Now I want to pipe this promise to another actor.
Patterns.pipe works with Akka future. How can I achieve this pattern using F.Promise?

Comment: What is F in F.Promise? You'd need to wrap that in an Akka Future.

Answer (score 0):

In Akka 2.0.2 a Promise IS-A Future, so just: promise pipeTo actor

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.3/#akka.dispatch.Promise

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "sender" command if you are traversing in 3 layer of actor system.
it will send back a data to the actor who is using the future and by this you can pipe it to another actor you want.